# Evaluating a contour integral using the Estimation Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have the following question:

Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+2z}{z^2+4}dz$$ where the contour $\gamma$ is

- The circle of radius $2$ centered at $2i$, traversed once anti-clockwise.

So we have $\gamma(t)=2 e^{it}+2i$.

I am pretty sure I am required to use the Estimation lemma, I've seen similar questions asked but none really which explicitly make use of the Estimation Lemma.

I have my own attempt below:

We can note that $\gamma_R(t)=Re^{it}$ for $R>2$ and $f(z)$ is differentiable on $D=\mathbb C/ (\pm2i)$

$\bigg\vert\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{z^2+2z}{z^2+4}dz \bigg\vert \leq \bigg\vert\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{1}{z^2+4}dz\bigg\vert \leq \int_{\gamma_R}\frac{1}{\vert z^2+4z\vert}dz$

$ \leq max_{z \in \gamma_R}\bigg(\frac{1}{\vert z\vert^2-4}\bigg)L_{\gamma_R} = \frac {1}{R^2-4}L_{\gamma_R}=\frac{2\pi R}{R^2-4} \rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty 
$

So I attempted this following an alternative example I was shown, however I don't feel like the steps are as applicable here.. I'm not entirely sure. I have seen others attempting with partial fractions but I am struggling to put the Estimation Lemma in practise really so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use residues?

Comment: @Nick I have emailed my lecturer about this as I have noticed it is an easier way to solve this type of problem. However, we have not been taught this yet and his examples made use of the estimation lemma so I assumed that's what I am required to do too.

Comment: The estimation lemma doesn't work well for this integral. Have you already learnt the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes actually we did cover that, would that be easier to do with this example?

Comment: It would. Consider $f(z) = \frac{z^2 + 2z}{z + 2i}$.